# Concatenate two immutable maps - which elements are preferred?

Tags: scala, dictionary

When concatenating two immutable maps, it seems that the elements of the right operand will "overwrite" the elements of the left one:

```
scala> List((1, 2), (5, 6)).toMap ++ List((5, 9)).toMap
res13: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 5 -> 9)

scala> List((5, 9)).toMap ++ List((1, 2), (5, 6)).toMap
res14: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(5 -> 6, 1 -> 2)
```

I would like to know, if this is a rule in Scala ?

From the Scala API I could not figure out this question.

Answer (score 27):

Yes, this behaviour is constant

Comment: Thank you. If you can also tell me why (or give a reference where the rule is defined), you will get the accepted answer. :-)

Comment: In most cases the implementation of `++` relies on `+`, which in its turn relies on `updated` and in [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html) scaladoc it is stated that `updated` returns a new immutable map updated with the new values. Yeah, I know, not an absolute proof, so probably you shouldn't close this question yet and wait for a better reference. The "Java Map" reference is bull$hit though.

Answer (score 15):

`Map.++` [is defined as](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/MapLike.scala):

```
override def ++[B1 >: B](xs: GenTraversableOnce[(A, B1)]): immutable.Map[A, B1] =
    ((repr: immutable.Map[A, B1]) /: xs.seq) (_ + _)
```

where `repr` is your current map and `xs.seq` gives you a sequence of the pairs/mappings stored in the map you pass to `++`.

`Map./:` [is described as](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html):

```
def /:[B](z: B)(op: (B, (A, B)) ⇒ B): B

Applies a binary operator to a start value and all elements of this
immutable map, going left to right.

Note: /: is alternate syntax for foldLeft;
z /: xs is the same as xs foldLeft z.
```

Note that it is not specified what "from left to right" means for an unordered map.

The following illustrates what happens behind the scene by reimplementing `++` and augmenting it with debug `println` statements:

```
val m1 = Map(1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C")
val m2 = Map(2 -> "X", 3 -> "Y", 4 -> "Z")

println(m1.repr)
  /* Map(1 -> A, 2 -> B, 3 -> C) */
println(m1.repr.getClass.getName)
  /* scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3 */

def ++[K, V](ts: Map[K, V], xs: Map[K, V]): Map[K, V] =
  (ts /: xs)  {case (acc, entry) =>
                println("acc = " + acc)
                println("entry = " + entry)
                acc + entry
              }

val m3 = ++(m1, m2)
  /*
    acc = Map(1 -> A, 2 -> B, 3 -> C)
    entry = (2,X)
    acc = Map(1 -> A, 2 -> X, 3 -> C)
    entry = (3,Y)
    acc = Map(1 -> A, 2 -> X, 3 -> Y)
    entry = (4,Z)
  */

println(m3)
  /* Map(1 -> A, 2 -> X, 3 -> Y, 4 -> Z) */
```

Comment: in your method ++, you're not getting xs.seq like you explained earlier. Why is this?

Comment: @Felix `immutable.Map` overrides `def seq` to return itself, i.e., `this`, `xs.seq` therefore evaluates to the same map as `xs` does. I assume that one could override `def seq` in subclasses, but I don't know enough of the internal design of the collections library to see when that would be useful or even necessary.